# what does it mean :I want to do research for a bachelor

Tags: meaning

I am trying to learn English. Sorry if this is a primitive question:
what does the following sentence mean?

**I want to do research for a bachelor**

I am guessing that it means: "I want to get bachelor of university". Is that correct ?

Comment: Reading your sentence as it stands, it means that you want to do research on behalf of someone who is a bachelor, but I suspect that is not the intended meaning.

Comment: When I've got my degree .I want to do research for a Bachelor. ...

Comment: @pedramshabani When you explain what you want your sentence to mean, you need to use different words. You may also be interested in our sister site called [ELL.SE]. Mick has done a good job of answering what you *probably* want to know, but your questions are probably better asked on the other site. I hope your English learning is successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, *I want to do research for a bachelor* means that you want to do research on behalf of someone who is a bachelor (i.e. an unmarried man). If you wanted do do research in order to obtain a bachelor's degree, you would say:

- I want to do research for a bachelor's [degree]

However, students do not usually do research when studying for their first degree. If you wanted to do research having obtained your bachelor's degree, but without taking a higher degree, you would say:

- I want to do research **as** a bachelor

This, however, would also be very unusual, but it might be permitted under certain circumstances. Doing research while studying for a master's degree would be more reasonable:

- I want to do research for a master's [degree]

Of course, the normal route to doing academic research is to obtain a doctorate (PhD).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to pursue research while being an undergraduate in some field, I would suggest that you write

**I want to do research as a bachelor.**

"Do research for a bachelor" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thank you for answers.((   When I've got my degree .I want to do research for a Bachelor.))) ... This is the   complete  sentence